# WPA-PSK fails with netplan on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, netplan, wpa-supplicant

I would like to get help with solving my issue. I appreciate if I could get some advice.

## Environment

Netplan version

```
ywatanabe@host00:~$ sudo apt search netplan.io
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
netplan.io/bionic-updates,now 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
  YAML network configuration abstraction for various backends
```

OS version

```
ywatanabe@host00:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

## PROBLEM

**WPA-PSK authentication fails on my fedora31 desktop.**

```
Jul 26 20:42:05 fedora-desktop wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
```

Full log

```
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2200] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'yu_home_5GHz' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2201] Config: added 'ssid' value 'yu_home_5GHz'
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2201] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2201] Config: added 'freq_list' value '5180'
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2201] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2202] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2202] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2345] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jul 26 20:41:59 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763719.2345] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=COUNTRY alpha2=JP
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop kernel: wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop kernel: wlp0s20f3: send auth to 9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1 (try 1/3)
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp0s20f3: SME: Trying to authenticate with 9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1 (SSID='yu_home_5GHz' freq=5180 MHz)
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763722.2429] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763722.2430] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp0s20f3: Trying to associate with 9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1 (SSID='yu_home_5GHz' freq=5180 MHz)
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763722.2601] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763722.2601] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop kernel: wlp0s20f3: authenticated
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop kernel: wlp0s20f3: associate with 9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1 (try 1/3)
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop kernel: wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp0s20f3: Associated with 9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop kernel: wlp0s20f3: associated
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763722.2716] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul 26 20:42:02 fedora-desktop NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1595763722.2716] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jul 26 20:42:04 fedora-desktop systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jul 26 20:42:04 fedora-desktop audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jul 26 20:42:05 fedora-desktop kernel: wlp0s20f3: deauthenticated from 9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Jul 26 20:42:05 fedora-desktop wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=9c:ef:d5:fb:c5:c1 reason=2
Jul 26 20:42:05 fedora-desktop wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
```

This happens even though I set correct passphrase.

Netplan config.

```
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.11.10/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.11.1
      interfaces:
      - eno1
      - wlx9cefd5fbc5c1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
  vlans: {}
  wifis:
    wlx9cefd5fbc5c1:
      access-points:
        yu_home_5GHz:
          auth:
            key-management: psk
            password: rootroot
          band: 5GHz
          channel: 36
          mode: ap
      dhcp4: false
```

Passphrase in my fedora desktop.
[image]
[image]

I am able to access to *ap* if it is in *open mode* .
Are there any settings that I should look for ?

Comment: I don't understand, you show Ubuntu version and netplan package status but then you show logs from a Fedora desktop, which is not Ubuntu and does not use netplan by default.  Why is this information mixed?  Are you actually using netplan on fedora?

Comment: Ok I've read through more closely now and understand you're using Ubuntu in AP mode via netplan, and trying to connect from fedora.

Comment: The client logs claim the passphrase doesn't match.  You might want to check the logs on the server also.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, setting up an AP that's bridged doesn't work: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/83

I have a [testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshemgp/+archive/ubuntu/testing) where NetworkManager is patched for AP to work when bridged.  It's for Ubuntu 20.04 only though.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shemgp/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```